# If I'm on a Qantas 747-400, can I move seats after takeoff?

Tags: seating, qantas, boeing

I'm planning on flying to LA with Qantas soon and the flight planner on the site states that we'll be flying on a Boeing 747-400. I was wondering if i would be able to move seats to the upper deck after take-off if there is a spare seat. I only want to do this because I want to see how it is on the upper deck.

Comment: Which airline and ticket type are you on?

Comment: Have you tried asking someone from the airline staff inside the plane?

Comment: Im economy (haha) and, as i said before, Qantas (airline). I have no frequent flyer points or anything. And no, i haven't asked anyone from airline staff.

Comment: on the only airline I've ever flown the 747, the upper deck is business class. In general you can't just go sit in business class because you want to experience it. I suggest using seatguru to see if this holds for your particular airline

Comment: @Josh Pay for the first or a business class and you will fly on the upper deck.  http://www.seatguru.com/airlines/Qantas_Airways/Qantas_Airways_Boeing_747-400_4.php

Comment: Damn. Too late now

Comment: @Karlson In this case, just business class. First is in the forward part of the main deck on the Qantas 747s that even have a first class.

Answer (score 20):

**Sorry, not going to happen**: on all Qantas 747s, the upper deck is business class only.  See [SeatGuru](http://www.seatguru.com/airlines/Qantas_Airways/Qantas_Airways_Boeing_747-400RR.php) for details.

You're generally welcome to swap seats in economy class after takeoff though.

Comment: Worth noting that your link shows just one of the three 747-400 layouts operated by Qantas - but your answer is true for all of them.

Comment: And not only for Qantas, but almost every airline that operates the 747. I'm not sure that I've ever seen a non-freighter version of the 747 that had anything except business or first class seats upstairs - and even some of the freighters do. There probably are some all-economy exceptions out there, but it seems to be pretty rare. Of course the seats on the flight deck are also upstairs, but you're even less likely to get one of those. :)

Comment: While this does seem to hold for Qantas, I know that some Air France configs have a combination of economy and Preferred economy seat on the upper deck as I recently flew up there on one of them. http://www.seatguru.com/airlines/Air_France/Air_France_Boeing_747-400.php

Comment: JAL/ANA also have some all-economy 747s on domestic routes.

Comment: During [the Hajj](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hajj); a lot of 747s are retrofitted for all-economy as well.